# Issue deploying SSRS reports with Release Management

Tags: tfs, ms-release-management

We are trying to use Microsoft Release Management 2013 Update 4 to deploy our SSRS reports.  The problem we are having is when using the Reporting Services Deployer tool there is the -o option which states "Brute force item replacement by deleting before creating."

The issue with this is that if it a new report rsdeploy.exe will fail.  And if you leave -o option off with an existing reports it will fail as well.  Our current design was to have Release Management push an entire folder of reports for each deployment.  This folder could have new or existing reports in it.  So rsdeploy.exe as is would not work.

Has anyone had any experience with deploying SSRS reports with Microsoft Release Management?  And if so, how did you overcome this?

I could build out my own program to consume the report server management endpoint and do all the work myself, but if I don't have to I'd rather not.

I feel like there should be a simple solution here, but I can't seem to come up with it.

**Edit in response to Daniel's comment:**
The command I am running is:

```
RSDeploy -o -s http://<servername>/ReportServer/ReportService2005.asmx -t report -l "C:\reports" -f "/<folder>/"
```

And this is the message I get back.  In the example message below,  is already on the report server and  is not.

```
Report: <first report> created successfully 
ERROR: The item '/<folder>/<second report>' cannot be found. ---> Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ItemNotFoundException: The item '/<folder>/<second report>' cannot be found.
```

Comment: RSDeploy works fine with either scenario -- I was just doing it at a client last week. What's failing? Can you provide a log, as well as the parameters that you're passing in to your component?

Comment: @DanielMann Check my edit for what command i am running and the message I get back.

Comment: @larrydice, If you run the redeploy command directly in the command line, will you get any error message?

Comment: @Vicky-MSFT That is what I was doing above.  Those messages are directly from the command line.